# ipython not showing argparse help message

Tags: python, ipython, argparse

In my python script `myscript.py` I use **argparse** to pass command-line arguments. When I want to display the help information about the input arguments, I just do:

```
$ python myscript.py --help
```

If instead I want to use **ipython** to run my script, the help message won't be displayed. Ipython will display **its own help** information:

```
$ ipython -- myscript.py -h
=========
 IPython
=========

Tools for Interactive Computing in Python
=========================================

    A Python shell with automatic history (input and output), dynamic object
    introspection, easier configuration, command completion, access to the
    system shell and more.  IPython can also be embedded in running programs.

Usage

    ipython [subcommand] [options] [files]
```

It's not so annoying, but is there a way around it?

Comment: This might have been a bug - it works for me on IPython master, though I do have to use the `--`. What version of IPython do you have?

Comment: I found the pull request fixing the bug in version `0.13.2`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run your .py script inside the ipython. Something like that:

```
%run script.py -h
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an IPython bug, corrected in https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2663.

My `0.13` has this error; it is corrected in `0.13.2`.  The fix is in `IPthyon/config/application.py` `Application.parse_command_line`.  This function looks for help and version flags (`-h`,`-V`) in `sys.argv` before passing things on to `parse_known_args` (hence the custom help formatting).  In the corrected release, it checks `sys.argv` only up to the first `--`.  Before it looked in the whole array.

### earlier:

A fix for earlier releases is to define an alternate help flag in the script:

`simple.py` script:

```
import argparse, sys
print(sys.argv)
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False) # turn off the regular -h
p.add_argument('-t')
p.add_argument('-a','--ayuda',action=argparse._HelpAction,help='alternate help')
print(p.parse_args())
```

Invoke with:

```
$ ./ipython3 -- simple.py -a
['/home/paul/mypy/argdev/simple.py', '-a']
usage: simple.py [-t T] [-a]

optional arguments:
  -t T
  -a, --ayuda  alternate help

$ ./ipython3 -- simple.py -t test
['/home/paul/mypy/argdev/simple.py', '-t', 'test']
Namespace(t='test')
```